# Check if two Column Indexes are selected

Tags: c#, indexing, datagridview, multiple-columns

I need to find a way to see if the user has selected two columns indexes on a given cell.

Example:

"**cell.ColumnIndex == 2 && cell.ColumnIndex == 3**" is what i want when the user selects when click draging in the cells of a **DataGridView**, but the problem is that when i select by clickdraging it always takes the last cell´s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyfjT.png) selected index.

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgdTabla.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 2)
                {
                    ColumnaSelecc = 2;
                    listaCeldas.Add(Convert.ToInt16(cell.Value));
                }
                else if (cell.ColumnIndex == 3)
                {
                    ColumnaSelecc = 3;
                    listaCeldasSimples.Add(Convert.ToInt16(cell.Value));
                }
                else if (dgdTabla.Rows[rows[cell.RowIndex]].Cells[2].Selected && dgdTabla.Rows[rows[cell.RowIndex]].Cells[3].Selected)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Paso aqui");
                }                    
            }
```

Comment: What [SelectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86.aspx) did you use? - Also: _two columns indexes on a given cell_ a cell can only have one row and one column index. Try to be precise and helping you will be easier and maybe no longer even necessary ;-)

Comment: well, i ment to say if the user selected multiple cells on 2 different columns, there is a photo that shows the example btw.

Comment: This should return a `List<int>` with all ColumnIndices from all selected Cells: `var cols = dgv.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(x => x.ColumnIndex).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that's exactly what i was looking for AWESOME!